# What should be the minimum number of SMD components on a reel (minimum tape length) for a pick and place machine?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

What should be the minimum number of SMD components on a reel for a pick and place machine? Different scenarios are possible for each machine. In terms of professional machines, if everyone writes down the pick and place machine and brand model they work on, this may give an idea.

Euro Circuits

> Minimum tape length – extra components needed: The tape width should be at least 8 mm and we need a minimum 50 mm to push the tape into the feeder. For tube and tray components we do not have these limitations. For smaller components up to 1212, we require at least 10 extra parts in the tape, for other components we require 1 extra component.

[image]

> Source: [eurocircuits](https://www.eurocircuits.com/assembly-manufacturing-technology/pick-place/)

Comment: Is this note referring to two different issues? One may just be the required extra tape length (without components) to properly feed the machine. The second issue may be referencing the need for extra components in case of rework requirements, since error rates increase with very small components.

Comment: Hey Nedd The minimum length to be placed in the machine + the additional number of components required due to 20% loss for each SMD component. I am talking about the minimum length where both situations are taken into account.

Comment: Well the note clearly shows a " - " between the statements, not a " + ".  Also, a 20%  fallout for "all" SMD components seems high. You wouldn't want to do that for a high priced chip. You may want to verify the full requirements with the vendor/manufacturer of the equipment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of components on a reel is entirely up to the PCB manufacturer.

The issue is it takes them time to attach leader line to the reel so that the machine can 'spool' The tape up. Most PCB manufacturers don't want to take the time to do this so they'll either make you do it or they'll just specify that you have to have a minimum length.

Sometimes it goes beyond that and they don't even want to deal with that. With passives it's much cheaper to waste components than it is to spend the time to fix the reel in the PCB manufacturer's eyes.

In short: it's really up to the manufacturer. I've seen manufacturers that will take just about anything and attach leader line. I've seen some that specify a minimum amount. Usually with components that have a significant cost like tens of cents or a dollar they'll be understanding and not require a minimum amount, and attach leader line.

Lastly, you can find services to respool and attach leader line, it's usually the cost of an entire reel of passives

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/news/2588 I get it now.Thanks for share your experience